# Two dimensional vectors in Rust

Tags: vector, rust, mutable, rust-obsolete

> Editor's note: This question predates Rust **0.1** (tagged 2013-07-03) and is not syntactically valid Rust 1.0 code. Answers may still contain valuable information.

Does anyone know how to create mutable two-dimensional vectors in Rust and pass them to a function to be manipulated?

This is what I tried so far:

```
extern crate std;

fn promeni(rec: &[u8]) {
    rec[0][1] = 0x01u8;
}

fn main() {
    let mut rec = ~[[0x00u8,0x00u8],
        [0x00u8,0x00u8]
    ];
    io::println(u8::str(rec[0][1]));
    promeni(rec);
    io::println(u8::str(rec[0][1]));
}
```

Answer (score 30):

You could use the macro [`vec!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.vec!.html) to create 2d vectors.

```
fn test(vec: &mut Vec<Vec<char>>){
    vec[0][0] = 'd';
    ..//
    vec[23][79] = 'd';
}

fn main() {

    let mut vec = vec![vec!['#'; 80]; 24];

    test(&mut vec);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If the functions that is going to manipulate are yours, you can create a custom struct with the helper methods to treat the vector as 2d:

```rust
use std::fmt;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Vec2d<T> {
    vec: Vec<T>,
    row: usize,
    col: usize,
}

impl<T> Vec2d<T> {
    pub fn new(vec: Vec<T>, row: usize, col: usize) -> Self {
        assert!(vec.len() == row * col);
        Self { vec, row, col }
    }

    pub fn row(&self, row: usize) -> &[T] {
        let i = self.col * row;
        &self.vec[i..(i + self.col)]
    }

    pub fn index(&self, row: usize, col: usize) -> &T {
        let i = self.col * row;
        &self.vec[i + col]
    }

    pub fn index_mut(&mut self, row: usize, col: usize) -> &mut T {
        let i = self.col * row;
        &mut self.vec[i + col]
    }
}

impl<T: std::fmt::Debug> std::fmt::Display for Vec2d<T> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        let mut str = String::new();
        for i in 0..self.row {
            if i != 0 {
                str.push_str(", ");
            }
            str.push_str(&format!("{:?}", &self.row(i)));
        }
        write!(f, "[{}]", str)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut mv = Vec2d::new(vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 2, 3);
    *mv.index_mut(1, 2) = 10;
    println!("Display: {}", mv);
    println!("Debug: {:?}", mv);
}
```

The associated function `new` creates the `Vec2d`, have two main methods (`index` and `index_mut`, so you can get a index value borrowed immut ou mut) and added a `Display` trait to visualise it better (but it is stored as `Vec<>`).

Answer (score 4):

Did you intend that all of the subarrays will have the length 2, as in this example? In that case, the type of the parameter should not be `&[u8]`, which is a borrowed array of u8's, but rather `&[[u8; 2]]`.

Comment: I might have them different lengths. What would I use in that case? Also what would I use if my arrays are not square? For example if I have 4 rows and 3 columns. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Using type annotation

```
let mut vec: Vec<Vec<i32>> = Vec::new();
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**