# How to create a new 2d vector with same dimensions as another 2d vector?

Tags: vector, rust, 2d-vector

If I had an existing 2d vector (map) and I wanted to create another empty map, what would be the fastest/ most idiomatic way of doing that?

*In this case, I'm working with images as 2d vectors of `chars`*

I could iterate over the previous map

```
let mut new_image: Vec<Vec<char>> = image
        .iter()
        .map(|row| row.iter().map(|_| '.').collect())
        .collect();
```

I could use vec!

```
let mut new_image = vec![vec!['.'; image[0].len()]; image.len()];
```

Comment: Do you want it to reuse the heap allocation? Or do you just want to have two vecs of the same size?

Comment: note that there is a difference between both versions: If the length of the rows is different (`image[0].len() != image[1].len()`) the first version would create vectors of different lengths and the second version would create vectors of the length of only the first vector!

Comment: Also your second vec is always (only?) as wide as the first row of chars. This may not be an issue with grid datatypes where your 2d grid is a rectangular matrix with even row lengths, but you should check indices.

Comment: The fastest and (arguably) most idiomatic way of working with a 2D map is to use a single `Vec<char>` of length `width*height`, possibly wrapped in a `struct` that adds helper function for easy access by coordinates.

Comment: Oh, and the only possible answer to "what is the fastest…?" is: benchmark in release mode in your configuration. We can suggest different approaches, but you won't be sure that they are really faster until you measure them in _your_ environment.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
let mut new_image = vec![vec!['.'; image[0].len()]; image.len()];
```

It lines up with the canonical answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102786/two-dimensional-vectors-in-rust). It's what I would expect to see, anyways.